# Updating password using 'PUT' method

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, fetch-api

can someone help me to understand how to use the query function created to update a password in my database?

here is the query function in question

```
async function updatePassword(req, res) {
return db.none('UPDATE user_account SET password = $1 WHERE email = $2',
        [req.body.password, req.body.email])
    .then(function () {
        res.status(200)
            .json({
                status: 'success',
                message: 'Updated user'
            });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    });
```

}

here is what I tried to do with fetch method put

```
resetPassword(){
            fetch('http://url/example', {
                    method: 'PUT',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        email: this.email,
                        password: this.passwordReset,
                        
                    }),
            })
        // Converting to JSON
        .then(response => response.json())
        // Displaying results to console
        .then(json => console.log(json));       
        },
```

no error "{status: 'success', message: 'Updated user'}"

but nothing has changed in my database

**edit**: problem solved thanks everyone

Comment: HOW is an email a number?? `var email = parseInt(req.params.email);`

Comment: just in case: NEVER save passwords in plaintext

Comment: Why are you using params and body? seems odd.

Comment: 1. `var email = parseInt(req.params.email);` you shouldn't parse email to an integer. 
2. keep email and password in the body.

Comment: Thanks all I just made modifications, is it better like this ?

Comment: @BarreMathis are you sure that `req.body` contains the correct data?

Comment: I am not seeing where you `COMMIT` the `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

'UPDATE user_account SET password = $1 WHERE email = $2'
you pass the both req.params and req.body so in your case req.params.email pass the execution and success for it and i think this is the bad idea using both in one.

Comment: I made some modifications on my functions and edited my question is it better like this ?

Comment: password: this.passwordReset, what is passwordReset? in this field.

Comment: This is the new password I want to insert in place of the old one in my database with the 'PUT' method